# Is it possible to change which work item is associated with a check-in?

Tags: tfs-workitem

In MS Team Foundation Server 2010 is it possible to update the work items that a check-in is associated with? I was working late yesterday and checked in against the wrong items and would like to re-associate with the right work items.

Answer (score 3):

Work items are associated by linking them to the changesets. All you have to do is remove the link to the wrong work items and add the links to the new ones.

Comment: John, that worked perfectly. Just needed to make sure I selected the Changeset option from the dropdownlist and everything was perfect!